# Search through a text file for string

Tags: php, text-files

I get a user.txt file. There are all the users saved in this format:

```
Vorname: Michael | Nachname : Schmidt | Username: DarkDecipio | Passwort: 3609e297fb0b6fb1105cba71d5c024b3
Vorname: John | Nachname : Doe | Username: Dummy | Passwort: d78c03d72e72b44a131d255aec3c8a11
```

Now when a new User send a register form to the php file, i want to look, if the username is already taken.
So i must search all Username's, if there the sended username. But i can't do it with `strstr()` or something like that, because the Prename (Vorname) or Surname (Nachname) can be the same like the Username. Or the username can include a part of the sended username...

Hope you understand it. 
Note: I know it's a ugly solution to save users in a text file, but this is a project in my school and we MUST use textfiles...

Comment: Can you save the user data as JSON instead?

Comment: We MUST use text-files. For all save-things, we must use text-files :/

Comment: why not use a serialized array when storing it, then when retrieving it you can unserialize and treat it just like an array, then searching through arrays is as simple as if(in_array($username, $array_from_file))

Comment: the text-file must be well formated. So a serialized array doesn't look good. But thanks for this idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I can think of two options.  Assume $line is the current line in your file and you are looking for 'DarkDecipio':

First, use regular expressions to ensure you are picking up the section you want:

```
if ( preg_match('/Username:\s*DarkDecipio/', $line) ) {
    echo 'Match';
}
```

Second, split the lines by | and then use strstr on the third item in each array:

```
$items = explode('|', $line);
if ( strstr($items[2], 'DarkDecipio') ) {
    echo 'Match';
}
```

Comment: I also think about regex. But how can i realize that? I search with regex for (\'Username: + the sended Username '\)? 
But i can't comprehend your second solution

Comment: Ok i think i take your first solution. But two question to that: 1. What mean \s* ? I'm not familiar with regex. 2. Why you copare it with 1? I think pre_match is a boolean`?

Comment: @dTDesign: \s* matches 0 or more spaces, which ensures that even if the spacing varies between Username: and what you want, it will still match.  Actually, I didn't need to use 1 for the preg_match, so I went ahead and treated it as a boolean.  But keep in mind it can return a FALSE on error.